# Correct way to add modified check-command for Nagios

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nagios

I am running Nagios® Core Version 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I am adding a slightly different check_http defined as check_http_s. It appears that I can add this to any one of three different files:

```
a.  /etc/nagios3/conf.d/checkcommands.cfg
b.  /etc/nagios3/global/checkcommands.cfg
c.  /etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg
```

But it turns out, that Nagios cannot find the new check command unless it is in
         C - /etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg

Is this OK?
What are Files A&B for because it appears to me that they are not being used by Nagios in my case.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration files are all included from the main `nagios.cfg`. They are included with the following directives:

`cfg_file=`

`cfg_dir=`

So, unfortunately, there isn't any good way to just tell if files are in use - you need to travel down the path of which files are included, and then see if files are included from those files!

```
cd /path/to/root/nagios/dir
grep -R "cfg_file\|cfg_dir" *
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, this helped me find the issue.
In my nagios.cfg file, one of the config statements is "cfg_dir=/etc/nagios3/conf.d".

I moved my command definition for  check_http_s from "/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg" to "/etc/nagios3/conf.d/checkcommands.cfg" and nagios started properly.

My nagios.cfg file does not reference "/etc/nagios3/global/checkcommands.cfg", so obviously any  config in that file are not going to be used by Nagios.

Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it! How about accepting the answer, then? ;)